# newsletter software for IIS? (asp)

Tags: asp.net

here's my questions:

1. is there a good asp software component for creating + sending newsletters online (via browser)?
2. is it recommended at all to send thousands of newsletters directly off my IIS machine? (because of server load) or better using a standalone win-application for creating/sending?

i'd like to code my own software for that and think a standalone html editor which also creates the (personalized) emails + sends them would be a better alternative - what would you think?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly off topic but, you should at least consider using one of the very inexpensive or free providers that make doing this kind of thing very easy for you.

I recently evaluated constant contact, mailchimp and a few lesser ones, and was really impressed with the ease of use of Constant Contact. The price is extremely low. The one gotcha is that you need to make sure the email addresses you are using are from people who have specifically "opted-in". No unsolicited email allowed.

Not only does a service like this add a tremendous amount of value to what you are trying to do, they have a ton of functionality built in that you are unlikely to be able to code into anything you write yourself.

And to answer at least part of your question: I generally don't believe it is a good idea to bog down your own IIS server handling thousands or more of emails. When I have sent them, I generally off-load to another server or workstation.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) will be a better choice here.